How do I anonymize the e-mails inside of code or text so that I do not need to share them with ChatGPT?
I need to anonymize a pile of code or text files that sometimes have e-mails with person names or other company or institution names that I do not want to share with ChatGPT. The aim is to get a merger of many projects, see How do I merge scattered and intertwined projects from SSIS, stored procedures, and Access databases into one SSIS project with the help of a ChatGPT?.
How can I get rid of e-mails or replace them with some dummy e-mails so that I can enter the text in ChatGPT?

I do not know whether this is an allowed answer since the most of the following code comes from ChatGPT and the rules do not allow sharing such answers here. Yet, I do not want to share the code for the sake of the code, but for the aim of having the right - anonymized - input for ChatGPT. It is more a tool to get things done, it is an easy code that shall help entering questions in a secure way. That is why I hope that this is allowed.
WARNING: this code does not seem to work well enough. There is a remark below that the Regex does not catch all of the patterns, for example:

my_name@example.com

And:

you should only ever use the example.tld family as example domains

I ask anyone working on this to paste another answer or change this one so that it works.
# Import necessary libraries
import re
import json
import os

def anonymize_emails(file_path):
    # Regular expression to find emails
    email_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+')
    
    # Dictionary to hold original and dummy email addresses
    email_map = {}
    
    # Read the input file
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()
    
    # Find all unique emails in the content
    unique_emails = set(re.findall(email_pattern, content))
    
    # Create dummy emails and fill the email map
    for i, email in enumerate(unique_emails, start=1):
        dummy_email = f'dummy{i}@dummy.com'
        email_map[email] = dummy_email
        content = content.replace(email, dummy_email)
    
    # Create new file paths
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    new_file_path = f'{base}_anonym{ext}'
    
    json_filename = f'{os.path.basename(base)}_email_map.json'
    json_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), json_filename)
    
    # Write the anonymized content to a new file
    with open(new_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(content)
    
    # Write the email map to the JSON file
    with open(json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        json.dump(email_map, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    
    # Print the paths of the new files
    print(f'Anonymization completed. Anonymized file saved at: {new_file_path}')
    print(f'Email mapping saved at: {json_path}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Prompt user for the file path
    file_path = input("Please enter the path to the text file: ")
    anonymize_emails(file_path)


This code doesn't work. The regular expression doesn't match emails reliably (counterexample: my_name@example.com), you should only ever use the example.tld family as example domains, there's no reason to truncate the filename when naming the JSON file (and doing so will probably cause data loss, somewhere down the line), there's no reason to even use the JSON module in the first place…. There's a reason such answers are forbidden on most Stack Exchange sites!

I do hope you're not using this.

@wizzwizz4 I do not agree that truncation is worthless since adding a suffix on top of a full filename can make it too long. I also do not agree that the json module is not needed since saving the email mapping in a json file makes sense. Good is that you hint at the mistakes of the the Regex. I ran this code only on one file, and I checked it now and found that there was no e-mail in it at all so that I cannot say that I have really checked it, my bad.

I thought it would just work since I had done the same anonymization for an SSIS project with a pile of dtsx files and there, the bot found every email and mapped it to a new dummy mail, see How do I merge scattered and intertwined projects from SSIS, stored procedures, and Access databases into one SSIS project with the help of a ChatGPT?. Yet, even if this answer had wrong code, the question shows that you need to care at all and the answer sets the path to go.

Given the choice between two error conditions, "program crashes with a 'filename too long' error" is much better than "program silently overwrites one output file with another". If you run import this, you'll find “Errors should never pass silently. // Unless explicitly silenced.” in the Zen of Python.

You mean if there is more than one filename with the same trunk of 40 characters, they would overwrite each other. You are right. I will take this out.
